# Debian 10.x: apt full-upgrade did NOT upgrade my ZFS packges. Is this normal?

Tags: debian, zfs

as above.
setups I followed/used:

1. I installed 10.6 on my PC desktop I immediately installed ZFS (using
   steps listed here: https://wiki.debian.org/ZFS). My linux version is 4.19.0-12.
2. Created some pools.
   and copied some files into the new pool
3. I then run "apt full-upgrade". My linux version is now 4.19.0-13.
4. Reboot PC
5. I then noticed my pool is not getting
   mounted and running "zpool status" says the kernel module is missing

I had to manually reinstall the linux-headers-`uname -r` and zfs-dkms to get it to work again.

**Is this normal?** Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a normal result from following the instructions on the linked wiki page: it instructs readers to install the headers for the specific kernel they’re running, which has the unfortunate consequence that new headers aren’t installed when the kernel is upgraded.

To avoid this, and ensure that the appropriate headers are always available, install the corresponding meta-package:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-amd64
```

Comment: How about ads-dkms? Seems it’s the same deal as well from what I’ve read. Thanks again

Comment: `zfs-dkms`? It should have been upgraded automatically, unless you’ve adjusted the backports pin-priorities. Was it really not upgraded with `full-upgrade`?

Comment: Well the kernel modules (modprobe zfs returned an error) weren't present after the "apt full-upgrade" and only came back after I reinstalled zfs-dkms. I'm reinstalling debian 10.6 later and will repeat the steps (skipping pool creation and file copy) to confirm. Thanks

Comment: The `full-upgrade` would have failed to build the module because of the missing headers. Installing the headers wouldn’t cause the modules to be built either; that would have to be triggered, *e.g.* by rebooting, re-configuring `zfs-dkms`, or installing it (over the existing package). If you start from another 10.6 setup, and install `linux-headers-amd64` before upgrading, everything should just work.

Comment: Note that `full-upgrade` wouldn’t *necessarily* upgrade `zfs-dkms`, which wasn’t bumped as part of the point release; its last backports upload was on November 27, so a 10.6 system upgraded after then would already have the latest version.